# Css style not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, styles

this is my worksite - [mysite](http://constantin-entertainment.info/salisburylandscaping/) i have created a page and called it to the home page using the following code

```
<div class="hilight-hometext">
<?php if(is_front_page()) :
$home_page_post_id = 308;
$home_page_post = get_post( $home_page_post_id, ARRAY_A );
$content_home = $home_page_post['post_content'];
$content_title = $home_page_post['post_title'];
?><?php
echo $content_home;
endif; ?></div>
```

and the result is

```
<div class="hilight-hometext">
<div id="hilightbox">
<div class="hilightbox-text">
<h2>At Salisbury we want everyone to understand their landscaping choices</h2>
Our latest landscaping innovation is our Outdoor Vision questionnaire. We’ll guide you     through a set of questions that will help you realize what you want out of your yard.

</div>
<!-- end tier 2 text -->
<div class="hilightbox-action">

<a class="myButton" href="resources/the-outdoor-vision-tool/">GET STARTED</a>

Your Outdoor Vision

</div>

</div></div>
```

i have added the styling as follows

```
#hilightbox {
background: url(../img/action-bg.jpg);
width: 100%;
margin: 20px auto;
}
#hilightbox .hilightbox-text {
width: 75%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
}
#hilightbox .hilightbox-action {
width: 25%;
float: left;
padding: 15px 0;
}
.myButton {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #c9df23),         color-stop(1, #747728));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #c9df23 5%, #747728 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c9df23', endColorstr='#747728');
background-color: #c9df23;
display: inline-block;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 14px 14px;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #747728;
}
```

but the background image and the styles are not showing up.Please help!! Thanks

Comment: How are you importing the stylesheet into your web page?

Comment: i am not sure but your css may be overwrite by other css so try with add !important after apply elements like this width: 75% !important; and also inspect your bg image and find out the path is correct or not.@Melvin

Comment: its coded with wordpress theme

Comment: background image if you are checking this on #hilightbox as its childrens are floated #hilightbox not occupying full height you need to add css overflow: hidden; on  #hilightbox

Comment: @SmartKiller the path is correct also given  !important.. didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you just add this:

```
#hilightbox {
  background: url(../img/action-bg.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

it will solve you problem.
currently your container div `#hilightbox` does not know about child div's (`.hilightbox-text` and `hilightbox-action`) `height` & `width` because of `float:left` property.